# Number of proper vertex colorings where a subgraph of a graph has a fixed coloring

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, reference-request, coloring

Let $G$ be a finite simple graph, and let $H$ be a subgraph of $G$. Let $q\geq 1$ be an integer and suppose that $P_G(q)$ is the number of proper vertex $q$-colorings of $G$ (i.e.,proper vertex colorings of $G$ using at most $q$ colors).

I have been thinking about the number of such $q$-colorings, where $H$ has a fixed $q$-coloring. I wonder, if known, whether this number establishes a relationship between $P_H(q)$ and $P_G(q)$.

I have the feeling that it is not known in general and it is difficult to determine because when fixing a coloring of $H$, in order to form a coloring of $G$, one must carefully consider how to color the neighbors of the vertices of $H$ that are not in $H$. Nonetheless, I thought it was worth asking and if someone could refer me to a reference. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If you fix a $q $ coloring on some node of the graph, then you can reduce to a classical coloring problem with the following transformation:

Let $A$ be the set of vertices already colored, and $B$ the vertices that are not. We build a graph $G'$ where the vertices are $B\cup\{v_1, v_2, ..., v_q\} $.
All vertices of $\{v_1, v_2, ..., v_q\}$ are linked together as a complete graph. Two vertices of $B$ are linked together if and only if they are linked in $G$. If $u\in B$ and $v_i \in \{v_1, v_2, ..., v_q\}$, then $uv_i $ is an edge if and only if $u $ is adjacent in $G$ to a vertex with color $i$.

If $H$ is big, it can significantly reduce the size of the graph to color, but in general, it will no make the question easier. For example, if $H$ is reduced to a single vertex, we easily see we do not learn anything about $G$.

If you really want a recurrence formula, the deletion-contraction formula gives a recurrence linking the number of colorings of $G$ to the number of colorings of a subgraph of $G$ and a minor of $G$